# VB.NET Windows Form Designer Sharpdevelop

Tags: vb.net, sharpdevelop

I'm trying to use SharpDevelop for a Windows Form App. The problem is that I need to use VB as the language, and the Form Designer works for C# only and not for VB.
How can I solve this?
The software I'm using is SharpDevelop 5 Xcopyable portable version, because I cannot install any software.

Comment: Well, nothing would be stopping you from creating the code for the designer by yourself, it's just a question of adding the components at the correct time

Answer (score 2):

Older SharpDevelop versions (up to 4.x) had better VB support.

While there's no official X-copyable .zip file distribution for them, you should be able to simply copy a SharpDevelop 4 installation to another machine.